# TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium

What am I missing here? the script will click like on the first profile, but fails the next one.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.okcupid.com/login')
redirect = ('https://www.okcupid.com/doubletake')

username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("gmail.com")
password.send_keys("password")
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='login2017-actions-button']").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login2017-actions-button').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(redirect)

hoes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='cardactions-action cardactions-action--like']")

while 1:
    print('Liking')
    hoes.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

But when I make these changes, it doesnt work at all:

```
hoes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='cardactions-action cardactions-action--like']")

for matches in hoes:
    print('Liking')
    hoes.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

`Liking
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cha0zz/Desktop/scripts/okcupid.py", line 24, in <module>
    hoes.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `matches.click()` instead of `hoes.click()` ?

Comment: I think you are right :D what am I thinking @ksai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
hoes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='cardactions-action cardactions-action--like']")

while 1:
    print('Liking')
    hoes.click()
```

`find_element_by_xpath` returns a single object. Meaning you can call `click` for it (if the element was found, of course) but you cannot iterate - single element is not a list and doesn't have defined `__iter__` member.

In your other sample code

```
hoes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='cardactions-action cardactions-action--like']")

for matches in hoes:
    print('Liking')
    hoes.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

`hoes` is now a list, so you cannot click it but can iterate.
Probably, you wanted to click every member of `hoes`, which you can do with a small fix `hoes.click()` => `match.click()`:

```
hoes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='cardactions-action cardactions-action--like']")

for matches in hoes:
    print('Liking')
    matches.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank  you kindly for taking your time and explaining it for me :) It's very helpful, and what a small mistake got me thinking lol. Vote up

Comment: @uzdisral glad I was helpful )